# display data as it scrapes in php

Tags: php, file-get-contents, scrape

I have a php script that scrapes data from a website using `file_get_contents('http://remote_site.com/page.html')`. The only issue I'm running into is that it prints the data only *after* all the data is scraped and processed. Is there a way to `print`  or `echo` the data it as the script is scrapping?

Comment: have a look at [flush()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) in the manual. And don't scrape with out permission.

Comment: how are you scrapping the pages now? `cURL`? `file_get_contents`? Show us some code

Comment: Will look into flush() thanks Dagon. I an scrapinng using file_get_contents @Ben D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be working with (and flushing) the buffer as you're reading a remote file I believe that you will need to switch from using `file_get_contents` to use the `f`-commands (`fopen`,`fgets`,etc) in order to be able to process/`flush` the code as you're scrapping. [`file_get_contents()` does not support the offset parameter for remote files](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) so you have to wait until the file is read in full before you can handle the result.

You'll have to check that `allow_url_fopen` is enabled in your php.ini file, but you should be able to write something like this (modified from [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php)):

```
$file = fopen ("http://www.example.com/", "r");
if (!$file) {
    echo "<p>Unable to open remote file.\n";
    exit;
}
ob_start();
while (!feof ($file)) {
    $line = fgets ($file, 1024);
    $buffer = $line;//you can manipulate what goes to the buffer here
    echo $buffer;
    ob_flush();
    flush(); 
}
fclose($file);
```

You may need to play around with this, as I haven't tested it, but I think that's the approach you'll want to take.

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
<?php
print '<pre>'.print_r($data, 1).'</pre>';
```